# Why doesn't my ImageView as a button work?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, imageview, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make an ImageView button inside a fragment to open another fragment in a navigation drawer but I have encountered a problem where I can't set an OnCliCkListener to my ImageView button. I tried searching fixes on youtube but I can't seem to find a fix to my problem.

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk2Z6.png)
[Here's the error as text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GasjN.png)

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentHomeBinding binding;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    return binding.getRoot();
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    binding.IVOrdersButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment OrdersFragment = new OrdersFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_dashboard, OrdersFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
}
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    binding = null;
  }


}
```

Dashboard_fragment.xml

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/DashboardTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Dashboard"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/IVOrdersButton"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DashboardTV"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_orders"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_orders" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/OrdersLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ordersDashboard"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.187"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/IVOrdersButton"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Please post the error here as text. Your screenshot only shows code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. here's the error as text. "Cannot resolve symbol 'IVOrdersButton'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inflating `FragmentHomeBinding` based on `fragment_home.xml` but the layout with the imageview is called `Dashboard_fragment.xml`. Move the `ImageView` to `fragment_home.xml` to be able to use it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code again, it is missing @Override before the onCreateView and onViewCreated functions

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Most of the code is actually generated so I didn't paste it here but it didn't have an override before I typed the  binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    return binding.getRoot();

Comment: @Override is optional, no?